# Where to put score functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am implementing a score system to rank trending in a rails application. To score the items I'm using a basic number of likes x age.

```
@post.score = @post.likers(User).length * age
```

I have a field in the posts database called score. My question is where do I call the above code so that the score is constantly getting updated as it gets older or when someone new likes the post.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's an ever changing value, and not really a static field, I'd suggest consider putting this in a method, not in the database. Unless for performance reasons that is needed. So, in your Post model just have:

```
def score
 #score algorithm here
end
```

This way, whenever you call post.score, it will be calculated at that time and shown.

Alternatively if age is a daily value, you could use some kind of scheduled task (cron/whenever) to update this on a daily basis.

Comment: Thanks, never thought of putting it in the model.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work. Just make sure you call `@post.save` on the next line. Can we see your codebase?

Comment: So if I call this is in the create function of a post. I'm using rails. Every time a value changes it will update. Or put it in it's own function e.g def `score`. Then call @post.save in the score function.